# How to make Bootstrap cards the same height in card-columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha 2 and taking advantage on cards. 
Specifically, I am working with [this example](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns) taken from the official docs. How can I make all cards to be the same height?

All I can think by now is setting the following CSS rule:

```
.card {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

But that is just a hard coded solution that won't work in a general case.
The code in my view is the same as the one in the docs i.e:

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-block">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-block card-inverse card-primary text-xs-center">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer>
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-block text-xs-center">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" data-src="..." alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card card-block text-xs-right">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any efforts so far? Any code to share?

Comment: That example is for Masonry-like columns. The whole point of that style is that the cards are of *different* heights. Use a [deck](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#decks) and enable flexbox mode if you want equal heights.

Comment: The deck works only for cards in a row. What I want is the same effect of `card-columns` but keeping same height.

Answer (score 327):

You can either put the classes on the "row" or the "column"?
Won't be visible on the cards (border) if you use it on the row.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#align-items

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <!--CARD HERE-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <!--CARD HERE-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <!--CARD HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE BS5 FULL HTML EXAMPLE**

https://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/QWgwEeG

Comment: h-100 is not a fixed height, it's height at 100% (of the row)

Comment: @konyak yeah, I realise that buddy. I am not referring to h-100 (scroll down this page).

Comment: @Kerry7777 thanks for the much needed clarification, BUDDY! Also, for my case it was critical to add the d-flex align-items-stretch to the divs keeping my cards, but I also needed to add `h-100` to both the card and the card footers to ensure they all match

Comment: The technically correct solution is to use a Bootstrap card decks. However this solution works 100%.

Answer (score 239):

I'm using Bootstrap 4 (Beta 2). Meanwhile the situations seems to have changed. I had the same problem and found an easy solution. This is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid content-row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card h-100">
                … content card …
            </div>
        </div>
        … all the other cards … 
    </div>
</div>
```

With "col-sm-12 col-lg-6" I've made the cards responsive. With "card h-100" I've set all cards to the height of their parent column. On my system this works, but I'm not a pro. So, hopefully I helped someone.

Comment: so simple h-100

Comment: .h-100 - brilliant

Comment: This did the trick for me when `d-flex` caused issues with IE (which I have to support).  I just added a `mb-4` to the parent div to separate the cards a little more.

Comment: and you can also use .pre-scrollable to make it scroll vertically

Comment: I'd add .py-2 class to all divs with the .col-* class to add padding between the rows.

Comment: @konyak that padding was what i needed (h-100 is not compatible with mb-..)

Comment: @konyak or simply add `mb-1` to the column like `class="col-sm-6 my-col mb-1">`

Comment: Yes I can confirm this works! so simple

Comment: Thanks @user3350279 and @Muhammad Waqas Aziz both worked. 
But can we restrict `pre-scrollable` to particular height or we need to make a custom css for particular height?

Comment: Didn't work. Tried to add it several places, no luck.

Answer (score 147):

Bootstrap 4 has all you need : USE THE `.d-flex` and `.flex-fill` class. Don't use the `card-decks` as they are not responsive.
I used `col-sm`, you can use the `.col` class you want, or use `col-lg-x` the x means number of width column e.g 4 or 3 for best view if the post have many then 3 or 4 per column

Try to reduce the browser window to XS to see it in action :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row my-4">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bootstrap 4 Cards all same height demo</h1>
        <p class="lead">by djibe.</p>
        <span class="text-muted">(thx to BS4)</span>
        <p>Dependencies : standard BS4</p>
        <p>
          Enjoy the magic of flexboxes and leave the useless card-decks.
        </p>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm d-flex">
              <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                A small card content.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm d-flex">
              <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm d-flex">
              <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                Another small card content.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This answer works great! If you can't use 'card-column' or 'card-deck' to get the desired responsive behaviour in all viewports.

Comment: This worked for me. I have a column with one big card, and at right have another column with two rows. so, the left card takes the height of the two adjacent rows, thanks!

Comment: This was the way to go. I tried `card-columns`  but it could not take more than 3 columns per row. Thanks  for this answer

Comment: card-deck wasn't working in my case, your answer did the job !

Comment: Great answer, and if anyone is using BS 5, check the [migration page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/) as much has changed (including how cards are layed out) -- goodbye beloved `jumbotron`...

Comment: 2021 - Worked on AdminLTE3 with BS4 - This should be the first thing you try! If using `card-outline`, put the `flex-fill` on it, and `d-flex` on your column. +1

Answer (score 40):

You can apply the class `h-100`, which stands for height 100%.

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I did it:

CSS:

```
.my-flex-card > div > div.card {
    height: calc(100% - 15px);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row my-flex-card">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                aaaa
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                bbbb
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                cccc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                dddd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE:** In **Bootstrap 4**, flexbox is now default, and each `card-deck` row will contain 3 cards. The cards will fill to full height.

http://codeply.com/go/x91w5Cl6ip

The Bootstrap 4 alpha `card-columns` uses CSS3 columns which don't really support equal heights (except column-fill which is only suppored in Firefox).

If you instead enable Bootstrap 4 flexbox mode, you could instead use the `card-deck` and a little CSS to equalize the height and wrap every 3 columns.

```
@media (min-width:34em) {
    .card-deck > .card
    {
        width: 29%;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex: initial; 
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/YFFFWHVoRB

**Related**
[Bootstrap 4 Cards of same height in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451246/bootstrap-card-of-same-height-in-col/44456279)

Comment: I've forked your codeply to test out something; I need the titles to stretch out to be same height as well, which doesn't happen here: https://www.codeply.com/go/fqnQZ2ZGJy -- know of any way I can get my "Shorter title"s to take the same height of the longer title? I've tried playing with flexbox and grids but can't seem to get it just right.

Answer (score 9):

You can use card-deck, it will align all the cards... this come from bootstrap 4 official page.

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me. What works is class="card h-100" https://www.codeply.com/go/jbcgzs2Nzq

Answer (score 5):

I took a slightly different approach. Using the [Card Deck wrapper](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#decks)

I added a style rule that limits the height of the card block:

```
.card .card-block {max-height:300px;overflow:auto;}
```

This give the following result:
[image]

Comment: Use on card body like:   `<div class="card-body" style="max-height:300px;overflow:auto;">`

Answer (score 4):

wrap the cards inside

`<div class="card-group"></div>`

or

`<div class="card-deck"></div>`

Answer (score 3):

Another useful approach is [Card Grids](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/card/#grid-cards):

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

this may help you

just follow this code

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 h-100">contents....</div>
   <div class="col-md-4 h-100">contents....</div>
   <div class="col-md-4 h-100">contents....</div>
</div>
```

use bootstrap class "h-100"

Answer (score 3):

You can add `d-flex and flex-column` to the div with `card-body`.

Here is a working example :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-stretch">
      <div class="card shadow-sm mb-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
          <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Longer title here that wraps two lines</h5>
          <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
          <div class="mt-auto border border-danger">
            <p class="text-uppercase mb-0">Hello World!</p>
            <p class="text-uppercase">consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">CTA</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-stretch">
      <div class="card shadow-sm mb-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
          <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Smaller title here that wraps 1 line</h5>
          <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <div class="mt-auto border border-danger">
            <p class="text-uppercase mb-0">Hello World!</p>
            <p class="text-uppercase">adipiscing </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">CTA</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 d-flex align-self-stretch">
      <div class="card shadow-sm mb-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
          <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Longer title here that wraps 3 lines, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h5>
          <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <div class="mt-auto border border-danger">
            <p class="text-uppercase mb-0">Hello World!</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">CTA</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-12 d-flex align-items-stretch"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a novice at this so please forgive if I am missing something all together.

I tried many of the above. If you set the height = 100% the card will always expand to the greatest length of the longest card. The container will constrain all to the same length.

I wanted to see the container, so I used background color to help me see what was going on.

```
<div class="col-lg-3"  style="background-color: rosybrown;">
    <div class="card w-100" Style="height: 100%">
        <div class="card-body">
            <img src="images/beHappy.png" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-25 mb-3">
            <h4>CBe Happy</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap 5 and 4

HEIGHT-put your all card in div with class="card-deck"

WIDTH -give your all card style  {min-width: 50ch}

Comment: This question is very old and has many answers, please explain why is your approach different and new?

Comment: It work perfectly for me and it is pretty easy.
And it is also responsive becoz of min-width(in place of width)

Comment: According to the 5.2 doc, `card-deck` class no longer exist : "Dropped .card-deck in favor of our grid. Wrap your cards in column classes and add a parent .row-cols-* container to recreate card decks (but with more control over responsive alignment)." source : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#card

Answer (score 2):

According to the question I have an answer it may help you and you can use it. You can just use `height` attribute and set it as `height: 100vh;` I have used `70vh` and cards will be fixed height which you have given.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <!-- Bootstrap 4.5 CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Bootstrap JS Requirements -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
      <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      /*Use height property to set equil card height*/
      .card {
          background-color: #56568a;
          margin: 10px !important;
          height: 70vh;
          width: auto;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
              <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img5.PNG" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <small class="purple"> Product Launch</small>
                      <h4 class="card-title">Leveraging Social Proof for Growth</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">Duolingo removes language barriers by connecting people that need
                          websites translated with students
                          that learning a
                          language...</p>
                      <p class="card-text "><i class="far fa-user"></i><small class="purple">Praveen</small>
                          <i class="far fa-clock    "></i><small class="purple">Today</small>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
              <div class="card">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img6.PNG" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <small class="purple"> ddc</small>
                      <h4 class="card-title">Leveraging Social Proof for Growth</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">Duolingo removes language barriers by connecting people that need
                          websites translated with students
                          that learning a
                          language...</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><i class="far fa-user"></i><small class="purple">Praveen</small>
                          <i class="far fa-clock    "></i><small class="purple">2 days ago</small>
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to the question I have an answer it may help you and you can use it. You can just use height property and height: 100vh; I have used 70vh and cards will be fixed height which you have given.

Answer (score 1):

Most minimal way to achieve this *(that I know of)*:

- Apply `.text-monospace` to all texts in in the card.
- Limit all texts in the cards to same number of characters.

#### UPDATE

Add `.text-truncate` in the card's title and or other texts. This forces texts to a single line. Making the cards have same height.

Comment: I think you are way off with this answer. 

Each card or section of a working web page will clearly have different amounts of text (characters) and use fonts/typefaces that are not monospace. 

Why would you want to truncate the text content that visitors (can't) read?

Comment: @Kerry7777, you may want to truncate a long string and add a "..." at the end of it to let the users know it has been truncated. For them to read the entire string, they will have to click or hover it. That way, we can make consistencies on the contents displayed. Because contents are not the same. Some are short, some are long, and our screen space are limited.

Comment: In some cases, it is only the length of text which makes the cards unequal in height. So this answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

If any card item height is e.g. 400px (based on its contents), because the default for flex-align is stretch, then .card-item (child of row or card-collection class) will be stretched. Making the height of the card to be 100% of the parent will occupy this full height.

```
.cards-collection {
    .card-item { 
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px 20px;
        padding:0 ;
        .card {
            border-radius: 10px;
                button {
                    border: inherit;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
     .container-fluid
         .row.cards-collection.justify-content-center
           .card-item.col-lg-3.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-11
              .card.h-100
```

Comment: This may work, but Bootstrap provides classes for most of the custom styles you've written. It's best to use what the library offers for future maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. You just need to put the `h-100` class on the card.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G5J7kLSz8YY/XtY-bTC3X5I/AAAAAAAAAh4/jLokDsDeiFQsbAtymxMCaElw9Qlx8OkfgCNcBGAsYHQ/s1600/bootstrap-illustration.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">In exercitation voluptate consectetur velit eiusmod sint minim duis cillum minim nisi aliqua. Id dolore enim laboris exercitation qui magna reprehenderit. Ad irure pariatur enim officia dolor irure adipisicing magna. Anim ullamco qui quis ullamco sint aliquip id culpa non nulla cupidatat consequat ex sit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G5J7kLSz8YY/XtY-bTC3X5I/AAAAAAAAAh4/jLokDsDeiFQsbAtymxMCaElw9Qlx8OkfgCNcBGAsYHQ/s1600/bootstrap-illustration.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Sint tempor velit anim eiusmod. Laborum minim aliquip eu adipisicing cillum cupidatat elit excepteur.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G5J7kLSz8YY/XtY-bTC3X5I/AAAAAAAAAh4/jLokDsDeiFQsbAtymxMCaElw9Qlx8OkfgCNcBGAsYHQ/s1600/bootstrap-illustration.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Dolore labore esse mollit in nostrud adipisicing velit in amet exercitation incididunt minim. Voluptate elit consectetur culpa fugiat elit enim incididunt magna officia esse. Nulla est duis in enim id consequat cupidatat dolor eu elit velit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

[See Codepen example](https://codepen.io/wande-cole/pen/oNaGapO)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `$card-height: 100%` in Sass, which was~ `null` by default

Answer (score -3):

this worked fine for me:

```
<div class="card card-body " style="height:80% !important">
```

forcing our CSS over the bootstraps general CSS.

Comment: Very bad approach, you should avoid this at all costs!

Comment: Fixed heights are bad and inline styles are bad, especially with a style library.

Answer (score -4):

If anyone is interested, there is a jquery plugin called: jquery.matchHeight.js

https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

*matchHeight makes the height of all selected elements exactly equal.
It handles many edge cases that cause similar plugins to fail.*

For a row of cards, I use:

```
<div class="row match-height">
```

Then enable site-wide:

```
$('.row.match-height').each(function() {
   $(this).find('.card').not('.card .card').matchHeight(); // Not .card .card prevents collapsible cards from taking height
});
```

Answer (score -17):

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e87kvzp/)**

Just add the height you want with CSS, example:

```
.card{
    height: 350px;
}
```

You will have to add your own CSS.

If you check the documentation, this is for ***Masonry*** style - the point of that is they are not all the same height.

Comment: Seems that the content in the cards is not properly aligned. This solution is too manual I wonder if there's something more "smart"

Comment: You could try something with jQuery, to dynamically create the height. Depends what you want to do with them.

Comment: Just very curious to know why there so many down vote for the answer? cuz it seems it works

Comment: Doesn't this mean the card remains a fixed height, not a responsive equal height?