# Bootstrap 4 Cards of same height in columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on Cards from Bootstrap.

Depending on the text title I will get the different height for the cards and would like to have the same height as the tallest one.

I don't mind using JS I actually think is probably the best way to approach the problem.

I have tried using different solutions from the CSS like using flexbox.

The rendered HTML as it is rendered dynamically here's a simple example:

```css
.card {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .75rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.card>img {
  margin-bottom: .75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 85%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>SMITE FR</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/album.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="navigation.html">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="BeatsX">
            <h1 class="card-title">BeatsX</h1>
            <div class="text-center">
              <p>1188.0000</p>
              <p>2017-06-09 10:00:00</p>
              <a href="god.php?ID=2" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="Nitendo Switch">
            <h1 class="card-title">Nitendo Switch</h1>
            <div class="text-center">
              <p>2899.0000</p>
              <p>2017-06-10 10:00:00</p>
              <a href="god.php?ID=3" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)">
            <h1 class="card-title">iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)</h1>
            <div class="text-center">
              <p>6388.0000</p>
              <p>2017-06-06 10:00:00</p>
              <a href="god.php?ID=1" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove your `.col-xx-yy` divs. Leave `.card`s as direct children of `.card-deck`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Bootstrap 4 columns already use flexbox so they *are* the **same height**. Just use **`h-100`** for height:100% on the cards and they'll fill the columns...

https://codeply.com/go/hKhPuxoovH

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="BeatsX">
                    <h1 class="card-title">BeatsX</h1>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>1188.0000</p>
                        <p>2017-06-09 10:00:00</p>
                        <a href="god.php?ID=2" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="Nitendo Switch">
                    <h1 class="card-title">Nitendo Switch</h1>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>2899.0000</p>
                        <p>2017-06-10 10:00:00</p>
                        <a href="god.php?ID=3" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)">
                    <h1 class="card-title">iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)</h1>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>6388.0000</p>
                        <p>2017-06-06 10:00:00</p>
                        <a href="god.php?ID=1" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Also there is no reason to float the cards, and the `.col-*` should be directly in the `.row`, not `.card-deck`

Comment: Thanks so much and I removed the `.card-deck` thanks for the information

Comment: Hui, so many times I was fighting this equal-heights battle. Finally, a very easy solution without Javascript. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use card-deck for equal size card this below code works for me

```
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x180" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-2">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Reference you can find here](https://www.codeply.com/go/hKhPuxoovH)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know not doable without either javascript or flexbox (https://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback)

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` for get it below an example

```css
        .main {
            display: flex;
        }
        .child {
            flex:1;
            border:1px solid tomato;
        }
        .content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
        }
        .content-child{
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-child">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-child">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Flexbox` you got the equal height of the card

```css
.card-deck {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.card > img {
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 85%;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
  .card-deck {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="BeatsX">
          <h1 class="card-title">BeatsX</h1>
          <div class="text-center">
            <p>1188.0000</p>
            <p>2017-06-09 10:00:00</p>
            <a href="god.php?ID=2" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="Nitendo Switch">
          <h1 class="card-title">Nitendo Switch</h1>
          <div class="text-center">
            <p>2899.0000</p>
            <p>2017-06-10 10:00:00</p>
            <a href="god.php?ID=3" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/dieux/Agni.jpg" alt="iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)">
          <h1 class="card-title">iPhone 7 128GB (Jet Blakc)</h1>
          <div class="text-center">
            <p>6388.0000</p>
            <p>2017-06-06 10:00:00</p>
            <a href="god.php?ID=1" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Voir la Fiche</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height to card see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj1991/v6t8g7uz/1/)

```
.card {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .75rem;
    height:80vh;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.3px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: `height:80vh` it is not responsive way

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <!--YOUR CARD HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```