# Bootstrap 4 card equal height with text & image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have card in bootstrap 4. It is populated dynamically from database with text & image. if image is null or empty or card text is big then card height is increased. It is very annoyed to see. Here is the image

[image]

Above attached image show two card. One has image and another has no image. card not shows equal. Besides without card image , text placed in top. I have used bellow code to populate

```
           var html = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
                var item = data[i];
                 var img = item.photo;
                 html += '<div class="card row-eq-height" style="margin-right: 1rem !important; "  title="click add '+item.name+' to cart">';
                html += '<img class="card-img-top" src="'+img+'" alt="Card image cap" style="widht:50px;height:100px;">';
                html += '<div class="card-body" style="padding:2px 5px;">';
                html += '<p class="card-text" style="line-height:1.0em;overflow-y: auto;  max-height: 50px;">'+item.name+'</p>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
            }
```

I want keep equal height & width of each card. if image empty text show bellow. If text is big text will be scroll .

Please help me to find out the solution

Comment: I believe you should put Bootstrap's ```row-eq-height``` class on the container for the cards and not the cards themselves as done in [this example from their site](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/).

Comment: There's no reason to use row-eq-height and that's *not* a Bootstrap class. And, `http://getbootstrap.com.vn/` is a 3rd party port of Bootstrap 3.x. Please show all of the relevant HTML markup as it's rendered. Bootstrap 4 columns are equal height: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451246/bootstrap-4-cards-of-same-height-in-columns