# bootstrap 4 column height issue after background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive

i am writing a bootstrap code, inside columns i have defined div with background color but, background color roll till content only and due to data variation so, it look uneven data some columns taller and some smaller. I opted this approach because i need spacing between columns so, that it should look like cards with rounded edges. how can i have same height of column.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-2">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:aqua">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:pink">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:green">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text here</p>
    <h5>extra work</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451246/bootstrap-4-cards-of-same-height-in-columns/44456279#44456279).

The columns are the same height because Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox. Just add `h-100` (`height:100%`) to the rounded containers to that the fill the height of the columns.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <div class="rounded h-100" style="background-color:aqua">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="rounded h-100" style="background-color:pink">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="rounded  h-100" style="background-color:green">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text here</p>
    <h5>extra work</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: basically i have tried giving height 100% what happened when we switch to ipad pro test mode all column expand till screen end with blank column.

Comment: Then why are you using `xl`? Do you want them not to stack vertically?

Comment: I am using it in both directing landscape mode and portrait mode.

Comment: I dont understand what the problem/question is. You asked how to get full height columns which has been answered. There's nothing in your question about mobile/ipad, etc...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your problem, you want all the `.col` to be the same height...

Adding CSS property of `height: 150px;` (enter whatever size you'd like) to the `.col`. However, if you want the background to be the entire background of the `.col`, you need to move that to that `.col` `div` element (where I put blue and orange).

P.S. the blue and orange is just to show you the height of each `.col`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-2" style="height: 150px; background-color: orange;">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:aqua">
    <span>some text here</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2" style="height: 150px; background-color: blue;">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:pink">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <p>some more text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2" style="height: 150px; background-color: orange;">
  <div class="rounded" style="background-color:green">
    <span>some text here</span>
    <p>some more text here</p>
    <h5>extra work</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any technical or coding based approach because it's hard coded methood.

Comment: You could assign another classname to the column div's and add CSS to them all at once (`.foobar {height: 150px;}`). If my solution and the other one from @codeply-er aren't what you're looking for, then I'm really not sure I understand what solution you want.

Comment: Oh i am already implementing height funda with measuring tallest column and keep same for other two. I was just wondering if i am missing any tailor made bootstrap class which will do the magic :)