# VMware Clarity - Same Size for all image cards

Tags: html, css, vmware-clarity

I'm using clarity design and i have cards that contain different size of images. How can i make these cards maintain the same size? 
[image]

HTML Code:

```
       <div class="clr-row">  
            <div class="clr-col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img previewImg">
                        <img [src]="../pic1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr-col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img previewImg">
                        <img [src]="../pic2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr-col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img previewImg">
                        <img [src]="../pic3.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Bootstrap 4 cards the same height in card-columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868756/how-to-make-bootstrap-4-cards-the-same-height-in-card-columns)

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look